# How can I change the value of an text/list, XPM-enabled field, with client-side JavaScript

Tags: web8, experience-manager, dxa-1.6

I have a situation where I have an embedded schema within a content schema.

The embedded schema has a field called, `horizontalAlignment`.

`horizontalAlignment` has three possible values:

1. `Left`
2. `Center`
3. `Right`

This is what the schema definition looks like:
[image]

I would like to be able to change those values without using the "field properties" pop-up:
[image: Popup that XPM creates for list field]

I have to create an editing interface that relies on certain values from my component to generate a preview (So I have to make a preview app within a preview app).

I am able to populate a `<textarea>` from a plain-text field, update that `<textarea>`, and have that update Tridion.

But I am not able (so far), to output text from a text+selected-from-a-list field, and update that field in XPM unless I use the XPM-provided selection tool.

How can I update a text field that is a list, within XPM, using client-side JavaScript and *not* the Text Field Properties popup?